# Use SQLite INSERT code with a string in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I try to insert all listview items' name to a sqlite databace but I don't know how to do that. I guess this loop could help me but faced error in 6th line:

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("LMDB", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (id  INT primary key     autoincrement, onvan VARCHAR , ahamiyat INT, foriyat INT, olaviyat INT);");
    String temp ="";
    for(int i=0;i<myList.getAdapter().getCount();i++)
        {
            temp = MyListAdapter.getItemTitle(i);
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('"+temp+"')");                  
        }
    db.close();
```

**2nd Question:**

when I delete a line from database is that "id  INT primary key autoincrement" rearrange ids? (for example -1 rest of ids)

Thanks

**Update**

I want to insert a string parameter to my table.I previously use this code to add a static string as a field name:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('Smith' , 'Max' , 22)");
```

When I use above code error of logcat is this:

```
02-04 10:15:01.181: E/AndroidRuntime(4161): at ir.clickteam.lifemanagement.AddActivity$1.onClick(AddActivity.java:109)
```

Comment: My question has standard parameters I don't know why he gave -1 :(

Comment: @barq db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('"+temp+"')");  line has runtime error. 02-04 10:15:01.181: E/AndroidRuntime(4161):  at ir.clickteam.lifemanagement.AddActivity$1.onClick(AddActivity.java:109)

Comment: Edit your question with the trace.

Comment: Don't use raw queries, use insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since your table has more columns than your `VALUES` has values, you need to explicitly specify the column you want to insert to:

   ```
   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable(onvan) VALUES ('"+temp+"')");
   ```

   where `onvan` is the column name you want to insert `temp`to.

   To avoid problems with apostrophes `'` in strings and such, consider using argument binding:

   ```
   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable(onvan) VALUES (?)", new Object[] { temp });
   ```
2. Identifiers do not change unless you explicitly update them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your insert query use like this

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable (your_column_name) VALUES ('"+temp+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Content Values, its better

```
db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("columnName", value);
            cv.put("columnName", value);
            cv.put("columnName", value);
            cv.put("columnName", value);

            long id = db.insertOrThrow("table_name", null, cv);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

            return id;
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
            return -1;
        }
```

tell me if you face any problems...

Comment: It works but don't you think it make code complexer ?

Answer (score -1):

- About SQLite database, pls read a tutorial about that, insert new record using ContentValues.
- 2nd, I don't understand what you are telling here. Why dont you describe it clearer.